# Pagespeed and AMP site

Tags: amp-html, pagespeed

When I use Pagespeed on my site, the  desktop site is used for both the pagespeed desktop and pagespeed mobile. Even though I have amp enabled and all mobile devices are automatically directed to the amp site. Is there a way to configure page speed to use the amp site for pagespeed mobile and the desktop site for pagespeed desktop?

Comment: `use Pagespeed on my site` - what does it mean?

Comment: Visit the page speed site and then type your site url: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsharepains.com%2F

Answer (score 1):

What would you like to see on testing AMP with PageSpeed? There can't be a case, where AMP would be slow - everything of performance relevance at AMP pages is ruled by Google, so it can't be slow. Any result you get with this test would let you make no meaningful insight.

What indeed could happen - that your AMP page isn't valid, and that is the cause of low performance. But, to get this into knowledge you again don't need a performance test, but rather the [AMP validation](https://search.google.com/test/amp).